# comparison between two date columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have two date columns create and close date.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7gZM.png)

I want find difference between closure date in row 1 with creation date of row 2.
 and print diff. between them in days

Comment: [Please don't post images of code (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Ya I have read this solution ,but what i'm intended to do is subtract closure date in row 1 with creation date of row 2 i.e '30-05-18' (crea. date) -'28-05-18'(clos. date).

Comment: Do you think `df['days'] = (df['date_1'] - df['date_2'].shift()).dt.days` ?